# Supermicro IPMI and Windows Share

Tags: windows, ipmi, supermicro

I am trying to do a Windows Share for a Supermicro IPMI. I go to "Virtual Media" and then "CD-ROM image". I need to enter:

- Share to host:
- Path to Image:
- User:
- Password:

I know to enter my Windows 2008 server IP in share to Host, and I entered the Administrator username and password. However, when I enter the path image as `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\OperatingSystems\CentOS-5.7-x86_64-netinstall.iso` I get this

> error: The image path is invalid or contain /:*?"<>|

Answer (score 11):

The error reported by the web interface is misleading - what it really wants is to have the `Path to image:` entry beginning with a backslash (`\`) so it would look like `\sharename\filename.iso`. The host name (or IP address) in the `Share host` field has to be entered without backslashes though.

The share has to be an SMB share, but at least the BMC thingy is using NTLMv2 authentication, so it works with current Windows servers out of the box (i.e. without modifying security settings or installing additional software) and presumably should also work with Samba as well.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with IPMI, so take this as you wish, but you should probably use an UNC path instead of a drive letter. After all, it's talking about a Windows share.

Try to create a network share on your server, with a path of `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\OperatingSystems\`, and name it OperatingSystems, for example.
Then, use the UNC path in IPMI, though I'm not sure in what format the parameters are expected.

Comment: This is correct. You need to enter a UNC path to the share, so `\[sharename]\[folder]\[iso]` (you can omit the `\\[computer]` part as that's taken care of in step #1)

Comment: Good to hear that, Jake. If you're satisfied with my answer, don't forget to 'accept' it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. It's what we strive for. :-)

Answer (score 3):

On my SMT-based IPMI 2.0, which is a rather old generation, a ISO-image won't mount no matter what. I had success via Java-console, which also allows mounting images.